# Looping Logical Operators on two different datasets to created a third dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I have two datasets Mtest & Ztest.  I'm trying to compare each values in the respective datasets to zero and use the result of the comparison to create a new dataset with the results.  The comparison should result in one of three outcomes.

```
Result 1: Mtest > 0 & Ztest > 0 <- "OW"
Result 2: Mtest < 0 & Ztest < 0 <- "UW"
Result 3: Mtest < 0 & Ztest > 0 | Mtest > 0 & Ztest < 0 <- "MW"
```

Dataset 1: Mtest:

```
  A           B             C
-0.0136       0.0078         -0.0234
-0.0377       0.1369         -0.0387
```

Dataset 2: Ztest

```
  A           B             C
-0.4283      0.4441         -0.6826
-1.888      -0.5877         -1.2024
```

Desired Output:

```
  A             B            C
 UW             OW           UW
 UW             MW           UW
```

My logic is not generating MW for Column B Row 2.  Below is a sample of the output my loop is generating:

```
  A             B            C
 UW            OW            UW
 UW            OW            UW
```

When I run the following loop, it isn't working properly and I have been having a difficult time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

```
testMatrix <- matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = 2)

    for(i in 1:ncol(Ztest)) {
  if(c(Ztest[,i], Mtest[,i]) > 0){
    testMatrix[,i] <- "OW"
  } else {
    if((Ztest[,i] > 0 & Mtest[,i] < 0) | (Ztest[,i] < 0 & Mtest[,i] > 0)){
      testMatrix[,i] <- "MW"
    } else {
      if(c(Ztest[,i],Mtest[,i]) < 0){
        testMatrix[,i] <- "UW"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help you can provide me on what my mistake is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over both, rows and columns. Right now you are always assigning the same value to the entire column. Try:

```
testMatrix <- matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = 2)

for(i in 1:nrow(Ztest)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(Ztest)) {
    if(Ztest[i,j] > 0 & Mtest[i,j] > 0){
      testMatrix[i,j] <- "OW"
    } else {
      if((Ztest[i,j] > 0 & Mtest[i,j] < 0) | (Ztest[i,j] < 0 & Mtest[i,j] > 0)){
        testMatrix[i,j] <- "MW"
      } else {
        if(Ztest[i,j] < 0 & Mtest[i,j] < 0){
          testMatrix[i,j] <- "UW"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  That worked!  I appreciate you help!

Comment: What I have noticed after running this loop is that there could be a problem with my logic when looking for an "MW" result.  It looks correct to me, however there are instances when it's coming up with a result other than "MW" even when one of the criteria is met.  I'm not sure if I need to start a new question or not, any help on the logic would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not pay attention to that issue. I edited the code example above to address this. You cannot directly check a vector of values inside an if statement. You either have to wrap it in `all()` or use the `&` operator.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!  I think I have it now using ```all()``` in the script like you guided me to.  Thanks again!